# Setting user preferences in Settings.settings in run time by setting Scope-Application

Tags: .net, windows, winforms, application-settings, settings.settings

> Is there any work around to save user preferences using application
>   setting file [Settings.settings] in run time by setting
>   Scope-Application, as we can do by setting Scope-User?

Please suggest?